# What is a difference between "speed up" and "speed on"

Tags: difference

In a book "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" there is a expression "The boat sped on."

Is this expression is exactly same as "The boat sped up."?

I couldn't find definition for "speed on" by googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "speed on" means to continue to move at speed. It is different from "speed up" which means to accelerate.

Dictionaries list "on" as an adverb with meaning "continuous activity" [sense 36](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/on)